# How can I install and compile xen from the source code?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen, hypervisor

I want to modify live migration code of Xen. I can only install it using Apt package management. However, I want to install it using source code to be able to compile it after modification. Which steps should I follow to do that?

Comment: which platform do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to clone XEN repository:

```
$ git clone git://xenbits.xen.org/xen.git
```

Go to dir

```
$ cd xen
```

Switch git branch to the latest version:

```
$ git checkout stable-4.11
```

Or choose which one is needed for you:

```
$ git branch -av
```

To build all components (hypervisor, tools, etc) use dist target:

```
$ make dist
```

If you wish to just (re)build a single component you can use the appropriate dist-COMPONENT target:

```
$ make dist-xen
$ make dist-tools
$ make dist-docs
.....etc.....
```

If your host machine and target machine are different you can use cross compiler to build it:

```
$ make dist-xen XEN_TARGET_ARCH=<target_arch> CROSS_COMPILE=<path_to_compiler>
```

If you build for ARM platform you can take one which provided by Linaro:

https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/

A lot of good information exists on XEN wiki:

https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Help:Contents

Comment: I followed the steps, it needs to build some additional dependencies. Finally, it worked. So, thank you very much.

Comment: I tried to vote for answer, but it can't appear now because my reputation is still small.